# Delphi XE5 Isapi on Windows 2003 R2 server

Tags: delphi, indy

Situation:
I developed a DelphiXE5 ISAPI Webbroker application on a VMWare workstation under WIndows 7 Pro 64Bit. Testing on that platform with the code compiled as 32bit (default for DelphiXE5) was successful. The program consacts Stamps.com via HTTPS and uses the Stamps.com SOAP web application to purchase postage and create a mailing label with a valid postage stamp (indicium).

The mailing label is created as a PDF on a Stamps server and they send me back a URL which I then use to fetch the PDF and save it in my local SQL Server database. This fetch is done using INDY 10.6.0.5040 (per Remy at Indy). As part of that fetch, the INDY ssl component has to load and use the OpenSSL libraries. These load OK in the test environment.

I then moved the program (compiled as 32bit) to the Windows 64bit 2003 R2 server. This server is a virtual server running under VMWare. I am sure that the actual hardware is truly 64 bit. The OpenSSL libraries will not load on that server. I have tried the most current 32 bit libraries and the most current 64 bit libraries. Same result ... not loading. I tried the ones that load successfully in test .. they failed. Using the Indy WhichFailedToLoad() function shows "failed to load libeay32.dll". Funny thing is , I get the same message with the 64bit libraries. The libraries, even though 32 vs 64 bit, have the same name, so i get the same message.  Now, my specific questions are ....

1. could there be a default area that the libraries load from and my placing them in the same directory as my program dll is not changing anything at all ?? Indy is going the default first and if they exist, that's the ones it is using. If so, does anyone know where that might be. I have tried to trace through the INDY code to see what was hapening but it jumps into assembler and I'm not a ms assembler programmer. I know IBM mainframe assembler in my sleep but MS seems uside down and backwards to me :-)
2. For Delphi experts out there.... SHould the program really be compiled as a 64 bit application and put in production and then use the 64bit libraries? In the test environment I'm running on 64bit hardware, 64bit host, 64bit guest on which the 32bit compile takes place. The 32 bit libraries work there and it seems that it should work in production on W2003 Server as that is identitical .. except for the OS version.
3. Could it be permissions problem with IIS 8.5 that wont let my dll read or load the OpenSSL libraries ? If so, any hints as to what ?

I have the DLL in the scripts directory along with libraries.

Who ever figures this out can get a job as my backup :-) ... really !

Comment: As your program is 32bit, make sure that your IIS application pool is setup for 32bit. (IIS Manager => Application Pools => "Select Pool"=> Advanced Settings => Enable 32-Bit Applications: True)

Comment: I have done that. The ISAPI dll wont load at all if that is not enabled. The program runs fine .. it's just this one piece of it that fails.

Comment: Does you application pool user has access to the SSL libraries (if you are running under the networkService account, you don't have local access...)

Comment: I think you are on the right track as I suspected a user rights issue all along. I'm not a IIS 8.5 guru. so .. 1. There is a "default application pool" and one that is associated with my application. How do I tell what account is being used to access these ?

Comment: Check the identity tab of the application pool properties. The default application pool runs default with the Network Service account. So best is to create a new application pool, assign localsystem (for testing purposes) and assign the new pool to your website

Answer (score 1):

If your program is 32bit, the dll it uses have to be compiled in 32bit.

As for the location of the OpenSSL dlls, in my case, on a Win2012 R2 server, I put them in C:\Windows\SysWow64\inetsrv.

Comment: Yea, I got that. The libraries ARE 32 bit because they load and work properly in test when the app is compiled as a 32 bit app. They just wont load on the Win2003 Server. I'm gonna check SYSWOW for the libraries being there also .. thanks for the hit .. i'll let you know what happens.

Comment: I don't have the exact same server configuration. However, it would never pick up the libeay32.dll when I had it in the directory with ISAPI DLL. I moved it to SysWow64\inetsrv, restarted the IIS service and it worked immediately. Thanks @chadkops.